# Is the size of set $A + B$ the same as the size of $(A \cap B) + (A \cup B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a set $A$ and a set $B$,

would $|A| + |B|$ be the same as $|(A \cap B)| + |(A \cup B)|$ since the union and intersection just complete each other to cover the same elements as $A + B?$

Or could there be a case where $|A| + |B|$ is larger?

Comment: What does $A+B$ mean in this context?

Comment: You do have $|A|+|B|=|A\cap B|+|A\cup B|,$ But $+$ is not defined for sets.

Comment: The size of all elements of A + the size of all elements of B. Sorry probably should've made that clearer.

Comment: $|A\cup B| = |A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ for all finite sets $A,B$, yes.  This is the two-set version of [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Rearranging gives the proposed identity.  Things do admittedly get a bit more frustrating when talking about infinite sets.

Comment: So without going into to complex topics can there be a case where |A| + |B| is larger?

Comment: Under any reasonable interpretation of the symbols you've used, no, even in the exotic cases.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.